# 1D FFTs of columns and rows of a 3D matrix in CUDA

Tags: cuda, cufft

I'm trying to compute batch 1D FFTs using [`cufftPlanMany`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/#function-cufftplanmany). The data set comes from a 3D field, stored in a 1D array, where I want to compute 1D FFTs in the `x` and `y` direction. The data is stored as shown in the figure below; continuous in `x` then `y` then `z`.

Doing batch FFTs in the `x`-direction is (I believe) straighforward; with input `stride=1`, `distance=nx` and `batch=ny * nz`, it computes the FFTs over elements `{0,1,2,3}`, `{4,5,6,7}`, `...`, `{28,29,30,31}`. However, I can't think of a way to achieve the same for the FFTs in the `y`-direction. A batch for each `xy` plane is again straightforward (input `stride=nx`, `dist=1`, `batch=nx` results in FFTs over `{0,4,8,12}`, `{1,5,9,13}`, etc.). But with `batch=nx * nz`, going from `{3,7,11,15}` to `{16,20,24,28}`, the distance is larger than `1`. Can this somehow be done with cufftPlanMany?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the short answer to your question (*possibility of using a single `cufftPlanMany` to perform 1D FFTs of the columns of a 3D matrix*) is NO.

Indeed, transformations performed according to `cufftPlanMany`, that you call like

```
cufftPlanMany(&handle, rank, n, 
              inembed, istride, idist,
              onembed, ostride, odist, CUFFT_C2C, batch);
```

must obey the [Advanced Data Layout](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/#advanced-data-layout). In particular, 1D FFTs are worked out according to the following layout

```
input[b * idist + x * istride]
```

where `b` addresses the `b`-th signal and `istride` is the distance between two consecutive items in the same signal. If the 3D matrix has dimensions `M * N * Q` and if you want to perform 1D transforms along the columns, then the distance between two consecutive elements will be `M`, while the distance between two consecutive signals will be `1`. Furthermore, the number of batched executions must be set equal to `M`. With those parameters, you are able to cover only one slice of the 3D matrix. Indeed, if you try increasing `M`, then the cuFFT will start trying to compute new column-wise FFTs starting from the second row. The only solution to this problem is an iterative call to `cufftExecC2C` to cover all the `Q` slices.

For the record, the following code provides a fully worked example on how performing 1D FFTs of the columns of a 3D matrix.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <cufft.h>

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

int main() {

    const int M = 3;
    const int N = 4;
    const int Q = 2;

    thrust::host_vector<float2> h_matrix(M * N * Q);

    for (int k=0; k<Q; k++) 
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++) 
            for (int i=0; i<M; i++) {
                float2 temp;
                temp.x = (float)(j + k * M); 
                //temp.x = 1.f; 
                temp.y = 0.f;
                h_matrix[k*M*N+j*M+i] = temp;
                printf("%i %i %i %f %f\n", i, j, k, temp.x, temp.y); 
            }
    printf("\n");

    thrust::device_vector<float2> d_matrix(h_matrix);

    thrust::device_vector<float2> d_matrix_out(M * N * Q);

    // --- Advanced data layout
    //     input[b * idist + x * istride]
    //     output[b * odist + x * ostride]
    //     b = signal number
    //     x = element of the b-th signal

    cufftHandle handle;
    int rank = 1;                           // --- 1D FFTs
    int n[] = { N };                        // --- Size of the Fourier transform
    int istride = M, ostride = M;           // --- Distance between two successive input/output elements
    int idist = 1, odist = 1;               // --- Distance between batches
    int inembed[] = { 0 };                  // --- Input size with pitch (ignored for 1D transforms)
    int onembed[] = { 0 };                  // --- Output size with pitch (ignored for 1D transforms)
    int batch = M;                          // --- Number of batched executions
    cufftPlanMany(&handle, rank, n, 
                  inembed, istride, idist,
                  onembed, ostride, odist, CUFFT_C2C, batch);

    for (int k=0; k<Q; k++)
        cufftExecC2C(handle, (cufftComplex*)(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_matrix.data()) + k * M * N), (cufftComplex*)(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_matrix_out.data()) + k * M * N), CUFFT_FORWARD);
    cufftDestroy(handle);

    for (int k=0; k<Q; k++) 
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++) 
            for (int i=0; i<M; i++) { 
                float2 temp = d_matrix_out[k*M*N+j*M+i];
                printf("%i %i %i %f %f\n", i, j, k, temp.x, temp.y); 
            }

}
```

The situation is different for the case when you want to perform 1D transforms of the rows. In that case, the distance between two consecutive elements is `1`, while the distance between two consecutive signals is `M`. This allows you to set a number of `N * Q` transformations and then invoking `cufftExecC2C` only one time. For the record, the code below provides a full example of 1D transformations of the rows of a 3D matrix.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <cufft.h>

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

int main() {

    const int M = 3;
    const int N = 4;
    const int Q = 2;

    thrust::host_vector<float2> h_matrix(M * N * Q);

    for (int k=0; k<Q; k++) 
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++) 
            for (int i=0; i<M; i++) {
                float2 temp;
                temp.x = (float)(j + k * M); 
                //temp.x = 1.f; 
                temp.y = 0.f;
                h_matrix[k*M*N+j*M+i] = temp;
                printf("%i %i %i %f %f\n", i, j, k, temp.x, temp.y); 
            }
    printf("\n");

    thrust::device_vector<float2> d_matrix(h_matrix);

    thrust::device_vector<float2> d_matrix_out(M * N * Q);

    // --- Advanced data layout
    //     input[b * idist + x * istride]
    //     output[b * odist + x * ostride]
    //     b = signal number
    //     x = element of the b-th signal

    cufftHandle handle;
    int rank = 1;                           // --- 1D FFTs
    int n[] = { M };                        // --- Size of the Fourier transform
    int istride = 1, ostride = 1;           // --- Distance between two successive input/output elements
    int idist = M, odist = M;               // --- Distance between batches
    int inembed[] = { 0 };                  // --- Input size with pitch (ignored for 1D transforms)
    int onembed[] = { 0 };                  // --- Output size with pitch (ignored for 1D transforms)
    int batch = N * Q;                      // --- Number of batched executions
    cufftPlanMany(&handle, rank, n, 
                  inembed, istride, idist,
                  onembed, ostride, odist, CUFFT_C2C, batch);

    cufftExecC2C(handle, (cufftComplex*)(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_matrix.data())), (cufftComplex*)(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_matrix_out.data())), CUFFT_FORWARD);
    cufftDestroy(handle);

    for (int k=0; k<Q; k++) 
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++) 
            for (int i=0; i<M; i++) { 
                float2 temp = d_matrix_out[k*M*N+j*M+i];
                printf("%i %i %i %f %f\n", i, j, k, temp.x, temp.y); 
            }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is more or less in line with what we are currently doing. Interestingly, for relative small problems (e.g. 64^3, but it seems to be up to ~256^3), transposing the domain in the horizontal such that we can also do a batched FFT over the entire field in the y-direction seems to give a massive speedup compared to batched FFTs per slice (timed including the transposes). I'll test it further, and will try to make a minimal example and post it here.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, idist=nx*nz could also jump a whole plane and batch=nz would then cover one yx plane. The decision should be made according to whether nx or nz is larger.