# How to perform cufft fwd and inv transform for a specific region of interest(ROI) in a bigger array?

Tags: cuda, cufft

Consider a image of size 1920x1080. How to do cufft R2C and C2R for 720x960 ROI?

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#advanced-data-layout

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, CUfft has full support for performing transforms and inverse transforms on a subset of data within arrays, via the advanced data layout features of the API. Quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#advanced-data-layout):

> Advanced layout can be perceived as an additional layer of abstraction
>   above the access to input/output data arrays. An element of
>   coordinates [z][y][x] in signal number b in the batch will be
>   associated with the following addresses in the memory:
>
> 1D
>
> ```
> input[ b * idist + x * istride]
>
> output[ b * odist + x * ostride]
> ```
>
> 2D
>
> ```
> input[b * idist + (x * inembed[1] + y) * istride]
>
> output[b * odist + (x * onembed[1] + y) * ostride]
> ```
>
> 3D
>
> ```
> input[b * idist + ((x * inembed[1] + y) * inembed[2] + z) * istride]
>
> output[b * odist + ((x * onembed[1] + y) * onembed[2] + z) * ostride]
> ```
>
> The istride and ostride parameters denote the distance between two
>   successive input and output elements in the least significant (that
>   is, the innermost) dimension respectively. In a single 1D transform,
>   if every input element is to be used in the transform, `istride`
>   should be set to 1 ; if every other input element is to be used in the
>   transform, then istride should be set to 2 . Similarly, in a single 1D
>   transform, if it is desired to output final elements one after another
>   compactly, `ostride` should be set to 1 ; if spacing is desired
>   between the least significant dimension output data, `ostride` should
>   be set to the distance between the elements.

You can find an example of working with advanced data layouts in cuFFT in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26918101/681865) Stack Overflow question