# Why Does cufftPlanMany() cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: cuda, segmentation-fault, cufft

I am trying to perform a 1D FFT of a 2D array in the row dimension using the cufft MakePlanMany() function.  Unfortunately when I make the call to cufftMakePlanMany it is causing a segmentation fault.  I am new to C programming and CUDA so I could be making a dumb mistake.  I am trying to follow the code example in this StackOverflow [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918101/1d-ffts-of-columns-and-rows-of-a-3d-matrix-in-cuda)  My data (phd) is stored in row-major contiguous memory.  Below is my code:

```
void bpGPU (float *phd, float *complex_image, int Nfft, int NumSamples){
   cufftHandle plan;
   cufftComplex *d_in, *d_out;
   int ds = sizeof(cufftComplex);
   ds = Nfft * NumSamples;
   cuMemAlloc((void**)&d_in, ds);
   cuMemAlloc((void**)&d_out, ds);
   int rank=1;
   int n = { Nfft };
   int inembed[] = {0};
   int onembed[] = {0};
   int istride = 1, ostride = 1;
   int idist = NumSamples, odist = NumSamples;
   int batch = Nfft * NumSamples;
   cufftPlanMany(&plan, rank, n, inembed, istride, idist, onembed, ostride, odist, CUFFT_C2C, batch);
   ...
}
```

I placed print statements before and after the cufftPlanMany so I know that is where the segmentation fault is occurring.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't look right: `int n = { Nfft };`     You are supposed to provide a [mcve]. I believe the compiler should be warning or actually throwing an error about that, where you have used it in the call to `cufftPlanMany`.    There are several other typos and omissions in the code you have shown, so I'm not really sure that is the issue.

Comment: @RobertCrovella:  That statement was the problem now it is working.  Thanks for pointing that out I feel stupid now.  My inexperience with C is really showing.

Comment: when I try to compile that combination with `cufftPlanMany` the compiler throws an error and won't compile the code.  Not sure what compiler you are using, or why it allows you to pass a bare integer as an integer pointer to a function expecting an integer pointer parameter.  Something doesn't add up about what you have presented.   Do you not even get a warning about the use of `n` in the call to `cufftPlanMany` ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella:  I am using the gcc compiler.  It had actually produced a warning message but it got lost in the many other warnings that I am getting.  gcc seems to be fairly forgiving which is probably not a good thing for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 1):

The value n should be an array and I didn't declare it as such.  Instead I set n equal to the size of the FFT which of course is not a valid pointer.  CufftPlanMany tried to access the invalid pointer and returned a segmentation fault.