# Double precision error of cuFFT with PlanMany in Fortran

Tags: cuda, fortran, cufft

Following the ([answer of JackOLantern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918101/1d-ffts-of-columns-and-rows-of-a-3d-matrix-in-cuda)) I'm trying to compute a batch 1D FFTs using cufftPlanMany.

The code below perform `nwfs=23` times the 1D FFT forward and the 1D FFT backward of an `n=256` complex array. It's to train me to handle the routine cufftPlanMany. As a second step, the `nwfs` arrays will be differents .At the end, I check the errors of each arrays.

Because of the data are allocate as:  `cinput_d(n,nwfs)`
I use th function like this:  `cufftPlanMany(planmany, 1, fftsize, inembed, nwfs,1, onembed, nwfs,1, CUFFT_C2C, nwfs)`

where :

- `rank = 1`
- `fftsize = {n}` same dim for each FFT
- `inembed = onembed = {0}` ignored
- `istride = ostride = nwfs` distance between two successive input and output
- `idist = odist = 1` distance between two signals
- `batch = nwfs` number of fft to be done

> ```
> program fft
> use cudafor
> use precision_m
> use cufft_m
> implicit none
> integer, allocatable:: kx(:)
> complex(fp_kind), allocatable:: matrix(:)
> complex(fp_kind), allocatable, pinned :: cinput(:,:),coutput(:,:)
> complex(fp_kind), allocatable, device :: cinput_d(:,:),coutput_d(:,:)
>
> integer:: i,j,k,n,nwfs
> integer, allocatable :: fftsize(:),inembed(:),onembed(:)
> type(c_ptr):: plan,planmany
> real(fp_kind):: twopi=8._fp_kind*atan(1._fp_kind),h
>
> integer::clock_start,clock_end,clock_rate,istat
> real :: elapsed_time
> character*1:: a
> real(fp_kind):: w,x,y,z
> integer:: nerrors
>
> n=256
> nwfs=23
> h=twopi/real(n,fp_kind)
>
> ! allocate arrays on the host
> allocate (cinput(n,nwfs),coutput(n,nwfs))
> allocate (kx(n),matrix(n))
> allocate (fftsize(nwfs),inembed(nwfs),onembed(nwfs))
> ! allocate arrays on the device
> allocate (cinput_d(n,nwfs),coutput_d(n,nwfs))
>
>
> fftsize(:) = n
> inembed(:) = 0
> onembed(:) = 0
> !initialize arrays on host
> kx =(/ ((i-0.5)*0.1953125, i=1,n/2), ((-n+i-0.5)*0.1953125, i=n/2+1,n) /)
>
> matrix = (/ ... /)
>
> !write(*,*) cinput
> !copy arrays to device
> do i =1,nwfs
>     cinput(:,i)=matrix(:)
> end do
> cinput_d=cinput
>
> ! Initialize the plan for complex to complex transform
> if (fp_kind== singlePrecision) call cufftPlan1D(plan,n,CUFFT_C2C,1)
> if (fp_kind== doublePrecision) call cufftPlan1D(plan,n,CUFFT_Z2Z,1)
> if (fp_kind== doublePrecision)     call cufftPlanMany(planmany, 1, fftsize, inembed, &
>           nwfs,1, &
>           onembed, &
>           nwfs,1,  &
>           CUFFT_Z2Z, nwfs)
>
> if (fp_kind== singlePrecision)     call cufftPlanMany(planmany, 1, fftsize, inembed, &
>           nwfs,1, &
>           onembed, &
>           nwfs,1,  &
>           CUFFT_C2C, nwfs)
>           !c_null_ptr  fftsize,inembed,onembed
>          ! cufftPlanMany(plan, rank, n, inembed, istride, idist, &
>          ! onembed, ostride, odist,  &
>          ! type, batch)
>      !subroutine cufftPlan1d(plan, nx, type, batch)
> call SYSTEM_CLOCK(COUNT_RATE=clock_rate)
>
> istat=cudaThreadSynchronize()
> call SYSTEM_CLOCK(count=clock_start)
>     ! Forward transform out of place
>      call cufftExec(planmany,cinput_d,coutput_d,CUFFT_FORWARD)
>      !$cuf kernel do <<<*,*>>>
>      do i=1,n
>         do j =1,n
>         coutput_d(i,j) = coutput_d(i,j)/real(n,fp_kind)!sqrt(twopi*real(n,fp_kind))*sqrt(2.*pi)/sqrt(real(maxn))
>         end do
>      end do
>
>      call cufftExec(planmany,coutput_d,coutput_d,CUFFT_INVERSE)
>
>
> istat=cudaThreadSynchronize()
> call SYSTEM_CLOCK(count=clock_end)
>
> ! Copy results back to host
> coutput=coutput_d
>
> do i=1,n
> ! write(*,'(i2,1x,2(f8.4),1x,2(f8.4),2x,e13.7)') i,cinput(i),coutput(i),abs(coutput(i)-cinput(i))
> end do
> nerrors=0
> do i=1,n
>     !write(*,'(i2,5(1x,2(f8.4),1x,2(f8.4),2x,3(e13.7,2x)))') i,cinput(i,1),coutput(i,1),abs(coutput(i,1)-cinput(i,1)),abs(coutput(i,6)-cinput(i,6)),abs(coutput(i,nwfs)-cinput(i,nwfs))
>     do j=1,nwfs
>         if (abs(coutput(i,j)-cinput(i,j))>1.d-5) then
>             write(*,'(i3,i3,1x,e13.7,2x,4(f8.4))') i,j,abs(coutput(i,j)-cinput(i,j)),cinput(i,j),coutput(i,j)
>             nerrors = nerrors + 1
>         end if
>     end do
> end do
> elapsed_time = REAL(clock_end-clock_start)/REAL(clock_rate)
>
> write(*,*) 'elapsed_time :',elapsed_time,clock_start,clock_end,clock_rate
> if (nerrors .eq. 0) then
>    print *, "Test Passed"
> else
>    print *, "Test Failed"
> endif
>
> !release memory on the host and on the device
> deallocate (cinput,coutput,kx,cinput_d,coutput_d)
>
> ! Destroy the plans
> call cufftDestroy(plan)
>
> end program fft
> ```

Is somebody can tell me why the following "many-FFT" sometimes failed in double precision but never in single precision ?

Single precision: "Test Passed"    ALWAYS !
Double precision: "Test Failed"    Sometimes !

Indeed, I checked the Device to Host data transfer. That doesn't seem to be it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is N and what platform and GPU are you running on?

Comment: N is 256, it's the size of each signal
I'm using a GTX 960 with 2GB of memory
I'm on windows

Comment: OK, so it is likely you are hitting the WDDM TDR limit in the double precision case. Your GPU is 32 times slower running double precision code than single precision, and you have a roughly 2 second runtime limit on a standard WDDM setup on Windows

Comment: So I think it's better to change the machine at least. It is not optimal to develop on a laptop. Thank you. !

Comment: @JordanHeraud you can change the WDDM setup on a laptop in windows easily

Comment: I see... Is it safe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to talonmies. It was the WDDM Timeout Detection & Recovery limit.

See the link, to [change the TDR](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/timeout_detection_recovery.htm)